# What is the difference between containMatchingElement and contain in chai-enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, testing, chai-enzyme

I have the following in the tests of a React component using [chai-enzyme](https://github.com/producthunt/chai-enzyme#containmatchingelementnode):

```
const wrapper = mount(<Something />)
expect(wrapper).to.contain(<SomethingElse />) //works
expect(wrapper).to.containMatchingElement(<SomethingElse />) //does not work
```

and wonder why `contain` works but `containMatchingElement` does not.

Comment: Refer the documentation and example here: https://github.com/producthunt/chai-enzyme.

Comment: @arpitjain: I had included the same link as yours. However, I can not figure out my problem. Would you enlighten me?

Comment: Sure. To keep it simple let's take an example of an array x= [1,2,3,4,5]. In contain: If you assert that x must contain all the elements i.e 1,2,3,4,5 this will return you true and if you assertion on subset of x then it will return you false. where as in containMatchingElement you can assert on subset of x. Hope it helpe!

Comment: I have trouble connecting what you said with the difference between `expect(wrapper).to.containMatchingElement(<User name='John' />)`  vs `expect(wrapper).to.contain(<User id={1} />)` on that link. If  `containMatchingElement` can match nodes meeting part of the props and `contain` matches nodes meeting all props , then won't it go that anything passes `contain` will automatically pass `containMatchingElement`?